# T-SQL stored procedure cursor error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The same stored procedure is executed on two different databases with different values, in one it's getting executed, in the other, it's throwing an error

> A cursor with the name 'ActivityQuizCursor' already exists

Both database are identical in structure.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information.  What does the stored procedure do?  (Show its code.)  What is the database schema, and what are some representative values?

Comment: A school db, it is used to copy previous section data to new section. But the same code is working for other db @davis herring

Answer (score 1):

You are using global cursor that will be defined each time you are calling this procedure and give you the same error.

Define a local cursor. Just put the keyword LOCAL after CURSOR:

declare ActivityQuizCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR

Comment: tried, now the error changed to foriegn key conflict